# How can I find the groups with size more than a value in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I read the data into a DataFrame and called it data. I have the following query in python:

```
data[data["gender"]=="male"].groupby('age').city.nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)


age
29    86
24    85
21    81
25    81
20    81
28    78
27    78
```

now I want to find those groups whose size is more than 80. how can I do that in python?

Comment: Which is the input format ?

Comment: Should this be tagged [tag:pandas]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your aggregation and sorting call is a pandas series whose index are the groups you are looking for. So to find the groups with greater than a certain `cutOffvalue`

```
cutOffValue = 80
counts = data[data["gender"]=="male"].groupby('age').city.nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)
groups = counts[counts > cutOffValue].index
```

And of course, if you want it as a list or set, you could easily cast the final value

```
groups = list(groups)
```